# Inequality operations on infinity

Tags: infinity

if $a(\infty)>b$ and $a>0$, then is it proper to write $\infty>\frac{b}{a}$?

Comment: What do you mean by $a(\infty)$? What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: By the definition of $\infty$, it is "proper" to write $\infty> \frac{b}{a}$ for **any** a and b as long as $\frac{b}{a}$ exists!  It is proper to write $\infty> x$ for any real number x.  It is NOT, however, proper to write "$a(\infty)$", meaning "a times $\infty$ since $\infty$ is not  a real number and that multiplication is not defined.

Comment: at first one might think of plugging in $\infty$ into $a$ like $a$ is the chart in the riemann surface $C_{\infty}$ containing $\infty$. why not preface in saying that $a$ and $b$ are real numbers or something?

Answer (score 0):

The details depend on the context.

#### Calculus

In usual calculus, it's not standard practice to write inequalities with $\infty$ like this. And $a(\infty)$ would just be a shorthand for a limit of the form $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)g(x)$ where $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=a$ and $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=\infty$ in that $g$ grows without bound as $x$ approaches $c$.

So I would say **no**, because inequalities likes "$\infty>\frac{b}{a}$ are not meaningful.

#### Extended reals

Here I will assume $a$ and $b$ are [extended reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line).

Since $a>0$, $a(\infty)=\infty$ by [rules of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Arithmetic_operations). Then $\infty>b$ for sure.

In the special case where $b=-\infty$ and $a=\infty$, $\frac{b}{a}$ is undefined. Therefore, the answer is **no**, not in general.

But in all other cases, either $b$ is finite so $\frac{b}{a}$ is defined and finite (so $\infty>\frac{b}{a}$), or $a$ is finite so $\frac{b}{a}$ is defined and not $\infty$ (but possibly $-\infty$) and we still have $\infty>\frac{b}{a}$.

So if you meant for $b$ or $a$ to be finite and your inequalities and arithmetic to be done with the extended reals, then the answer would be "yes".